# Is it right to use methods from one bean (component) in another bean?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

It mostly the question about application architecture.

We have service layer (`@Service HelloService`) and bean, that uses service methods (`@Component HelloBean`, with autowired HelloService). There are many methods in service and HelloBean aggregate many methods from service in single method. So we use this single method.

And we have another bean (`@Component GoodbyeBean`). And we want to use single method from HelloBean and should autowire HelloBean in GoodbyeBean to use this method.

Is it right to use one bean in another, or we should make some new service (like, `@Service GoodbyeService`) and repeat all code from HelloService? Or we should autowire HelloService in GoodbyeBean and repeat all code from HelloBean?

I realize, that Spring IoC contains all of these components and we can use all across Spring context.

What is proper way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not call HelloBean in GoodByeBean because as name suggest it is opposite of each other and it will be very misleading to any other person.

If there is some common code in HelloBean and GoodbyeBean, move it to new service may be called as GreetingService and then call that method from HelloBean  and GoodbyeBean

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think second part of your answer is more applicable

Answer (score 1):

If you are calling the method of HelloBean which called several methods of HelloService then better to call those methods from GoodByeBean then or rather if there is no change of code or anything then use HelloBean all over and call the same method.

If it is any other method which is not calling the method which we consider earlier then I guess it is fine to call method of HelloBean from GoodByeBean. Sometimes it may happen that you have to call the methods from the same logical layer.

Or as suggested by @Ankita Agrawal, copy the method in another class and call the method from HelloBean and GoodByeBean.

Comment: then better to call those methods from GoodByeBean - is it a violation of DRY (don't repeat yourself) rule?